# Process code without refreshing the page on a button click in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have recently learned php & laravel and developing practice project.
I have created a form on which there are following fields;

1. Mobile Number
2. Recharge Amount

I have form submit button and I am storing the record in the database on clicking submit button. Before storing the record into the database I am checking if the mobile number exists in the database or not and i am showing toast message accordingly.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validatedData =$request->validate([
        'mobile' => 'required|max:10|min:10'
    ]);

    $mobile =  $request->input('mobile');
   
    $userData = DB::table('users')->where('mobile', $mobile)->get();
    if(count($userData) > 0){

       toastr()->error('User Exists');
       
    }else{

        toastr()->error('User Doest Not Exists');
       
        
    }


    return back();

}
```

Here in my code snippet for store function.
The issue i am facing here is, a toast message is showing properly according to the database query but the form refreshes after clicking submit button.
I want to achieve the above milestone without the form being refreshed or something like form validation.

So my question is how can I achieve this without the page getting refreshed. Please guide.

Comment: You can use ajax jquery to achieve this! Refer this URL : https://www.tutsmake.com/jquery-submit-form-ajax-php-laravel-5-7-without-page-load/

Comment: You are looking for AJAX requests (or XMLHTTPRequest), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: In this case you need ajax, it will validate data without page refresh

Comment: You can store the previously entered values in laravel using `old`. But if you still wanted to submit the form without refreshing the page then i'd use an `fetch` method.

Answer (score 0):

Any code written in PHP is handled by the server, not the client. So it is the server who will check if the form failed or not, so the page will always refresh.
So there are two ways to handle this, First and the easier one is  to add `value="{{ old('input-name') }}"` attributes to your input tags.

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
<input type="password" name="password">
```

See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#old-input) for more.

Second is as mentioned by others is to use AJAX requests.